# preg_replace() with multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have trouble again with preg_replace(). I terribly need a book for preg_replace().

My intention is to replace **`<td> author </td>`** with `<td>  Level1 </td>`

Any ideas? The **`<td> author </td>`** is wrapped with other HTML elements:

```
<td align="center">
  <a onclick="return listItemTask('cb1','block')" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Blocked" src="images/tick.png">
  </a>
</td>
<td>
  Author
</td>
```

Comment: I'm not surprised you have trouble again. Using regular expressions to parse HTML is *asking* for trouble.

Comment: Every time "regex" and "HTML" are mentioned in the same sentence, somebody gets up in arms about this. The thing is, you need to understand the difference between parsing HTML and searching text that happens to be HTML. IMO, this is a valid use of regex; The functionality required for this question could easily be achieved with any regex-based search and replace in a text editor.

Comment: @Ryan Kinal: Normally I'd agree with you but in this case if parsing is not required a simple string replacement would suffice. And if parsing is required then regular expressions won't handle all the cases.

Comment: @RyanKinal: Write me a regex that handles the following case correctly: <td id="><><foo><><"><span id='<td>foo</td>'>author</span></td>. Those are valid ids in HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-id-attribute.

Comment: @mehaase Yep. And at that point you have to rely on a parser. If there are no nested tags, and the tags have no attributes (or even specific, known, same-order attributes with near-exact white space), you can (most likely) use a regex (or even a simple string replace, if the pattern is simple enough). Refuting a specific simple case with a generalized but complex one is not a valid argument. I'm referring, here, to the specific case in the original question, rather than the generalized problem of replacing one tag and its contents with another.

Comment: @mehasse Seriously. Tell me that `myHTMLString.replace(/<td>\s*author\s*<\/td>/g, '<td>level1</td>');` is invalid. I dare you.

Comment: @mehaase `var trolls = "<td id=\"><><foo><><\"><span id='<td>foo</td>'>author</span></td>";`
 `trolls.match(/<\/?(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/g)` ... enjoy

Comment: @RyanKinal Neither you nor I know the full scope of the requirements. Where does this data come from? Does the asker of the question control it? If not, it might change unexpectedly. Even the original question is ambiguous, because he says the author div is "wrapped" in another element, but that's not shown in the example. Sorry, I wasn't trying to be a jerk, I just cringe when I see shortcut solutions to difficult problems, because I've seen enough horrendous code that was hopelessly broken to know that naive solutions rarely last. Don't take it so personally.

Comment: @GGG You didn't replace "author" with "Level1", which was the whole purpose of the exercise. I don't know how I'm the troll in this situation. Look at the top 2 hits on Google for "parsing with regex". They'll both say what I'm saying. http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @mehaase no, instead I found each tag, which is more useful. Replacing "author" with "level1" in that example is even more trivial. `trolls.replace(/\bauthor\b/g, 'level1');`

Comment: @mehaase the point is the OP asked for a regex solution. You cen tell him that's not what he really wants all day long, but if that was his requirement (like, say, from a homework assignment) you're not really doing any good. And, you're still missing the point that in *controlled situations*, parsing text with regex works perfectly well. Notice how all of the answers are targeted at the actual *question*.

Comment: @mehaase I so apologize for the hostile tone. And I understand the extent of the problem. But *I* cringe when a simple question is answered with over-complicated (though memetically popular) rhetoric. Especially when said question was posted 1.5 years ago.

Comment: @RyanKinal For an experienced developer who knows better, I say let's give that person the shortest answer to the question he/she asked. But this guy is clearly a novice, and what's worse, stack overflow is a big resource for programmers out there who are googling answers. (I found this thread because I was looking for which modifier makes preg_replace work over multiple lines.) So direct answers to the exact question may be extrapolated into heinous WTFs by unknown quantities of anonymous users who stumble across this page. That's why I get knee-jerky about certain topics.

Answer (score 3):

From [Perl regular expression manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html): (or [PHP PCRE docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

> ## Modifiers
>
> Matching operations can have various
>   modifiers. Modifiers that relate to
>   the interpretation of the regular
>   expression inside are listed below.
>
> - s: Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character
>     whatsoever, even a newline, which
>     normally it would not match.

Comment: Since this is PHP, why not quote [the PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)?

Comment: @KennyTM: Because I searched for `preg_replace` and the syntax is not described there. AFAIK, PCRE should be totally compatible with Perl's regexp. I'll incorporate the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A little code never hurts...

```
<?php
$string = '
<td align="center">
  <a onclick="return listItemTask(\'cb1\',\'block\')" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Blocked" src="images/tick.png">
  </a>
</td>
<td>
  Author
</td>';

$string = preg_replace("/<td>.*Author.*<\/td>/s", "teste", $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

Do notice the [`\s` modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) used to allow `.` to match `newlines`.

Comment: @tweakmy I really couldn't tell by your comment if this is what you were looking for or if [you'r just playing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bow%20head "definition for bow head") but, if this is what you'r looking for, you should click on the 'V' next to the question (accept it). That will give both of us credit for it! Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)!

Comment: Indeed it does not. It ought to be required for a serious answer.